# SSH to Cisco device fails with diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Tags: debian, ssh, cisco

When trying to SSH from my Debian box to a Cisco router, I got the message:

```
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

There are some similar questions on this forums which claim to have the answer however I found them to not work for me due to small differences so I decided to post the question and answer here.

Comment: You'll probably want to upgrade that Cisco device to something modern.  That's no longer considered a reasonable key exchange method for security purposes and it will likely be removed in a future version of OpenSSH.

Comment: @bk2204 not everything is a router that can easily be replaced.  Legacy servers, for example, were built like tanks, and some are still running for important but niche applications.

Comment: Most modern Linux distros are going to have something better, and that's also true for pretty much any OS available in the last decade.  At worst, you can install a newer version of OpenSSH yourself.  It's very portable.

Answer (score 3):

To fully enable this for all hosts you want to connect to, system-wide, add the following to your /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Host *
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

To only enable it for your own account, add the same to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

To enable this for specific hosts, edit one of the aforementioned files and add:

```
Host 192.168.1.1
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

To enable this for groups of hosts and/or groups of users, [read up](https://www.openssh.com/manual.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{
echo -n 'Ciphers '
ssh -Q cipher | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//'; echo

echo -n 'MACs '
ssh -Q mac | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//'; echo

echo -n 'HostKeyAlgorithms '
ssh -Q key | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//'; echo

echo -n 'KexAlgorithms '
ssh -Q kex | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//'; echo

} >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: The only thing that worked for my CyberPower remote reboot switch.

Comment: The same for OpenWRT against Realtek drivers. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the next error that will appear after solving "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1" issue will be

> "no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa"

So the complete solution is the adding this to ~/.ssh/config file (not to main config):

```
Host x.x.x.x
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
    User root
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Replace the address of the host and the name of user with yours.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a Cisco router and linux ssh client for SSH Version 2

> A. On Cisco router:
>
> > 1. enable
> > 2. configure terminal
> > 3. hostname name
> > 4. ip domain-name name
> > 5. crypto key zeroize rsa (optional to wipe any previous)
> > 6. crypto key generate rsa (key size 2048)
> > 7. ip ssh time-out seconds 30
> > 8. ip ssh authentication-retries 3
> > 9. ip ssh version 2 (1 is obsolete and openssl does not support it)
> > 10. exit

> B. On client to connect (linux):
>
> > 1. Edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config

> > > 1. Host (url,hostname, or IP* of the router)
> > > 2. KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
> > > 3. Ciphers 3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

> > - note - above, the Host must match what is used as the host part in the ssh command
> >   build one for each referenced input

> > 2. Client connect syntax:
> >
> > > ssh 
> > > example:
> > > ssh -p 22 user@hostname

> Older Cisco devices only support ssh on port 22
> Even older devices, especially Catalyst-type and era switches, do not support ssh at all.

Comment: Why is there so much blockquoting?